# Interrail seat reservation + partial route ticket

Tags: interrail

This summer I am planning on traveling by train from Zurich to Dunkirk using an Interrail ticket. Since I live in Switzerland this would constitute an outbound journey. I want to avoid this by purchasing a ticket from Zurich to Mulhouse and use the Interrail ticket from Mulhouse to Dunkirk. I have two questions regarding this:

1. Is this allowed under Interrail rules?
2. Do I need to purchase two separate seat reservations (Zurich-Mulhouse, Mulhouse-Dunkirk) or would just one work as well? (Zurich-Dunkirk)

Comment: You would need a ticket Zurich - Basel, as you will be on French trains from there on. What route are you intending to take? My preferred choice would involve one of the few direct Strasbourg - Lille TGVs, and this would then be the only train that needs reservation. 
You do not need reservations in Switzerland. Not even for the TGV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Interrail rules](https://rail.cc/interrail-rules) state :

> > 3.2 Travel in Country of Residence with an Interrail Global Pass
>
> An Interrail Global Pass may only be used for two specific trips in
> the country of residence of the traveller (provided this country is an
> Interrail participating country). These two trips are referred to as
> the outbound and inbound journey.
>
> - The outbound journey can be used to travel from any location in the country of residence to the border or an airport or port.
> - The inbound journey can be used to travel from the border or an airport or port back to their (final) destination in the country of
>   residence.
>
> During these trips, the traveller may travel with more than one train,
> provided the trips are within the same day. Please note that the
> special rule for travel with an overnight train also applies. In order
> to make use of these trips, the traveller must indicate the relevant
> date and journey on the Interrail Pass Cover and on the Travel
> Calendar, in case of a Flexi Pass.

> Is this allowed under Interrail rules?

I don't know how this wouldn't be, but that Zürich-Dunkirk would very much be allowed under the Interrail rules (for way cheaper too, a ticket for tomorrow from Zürich to Mulhouse can be found for €50)

> Do I need to purchase two separate seat reservations (Zurich-Mulhouse, Mulhouse-Dunkirk) or would just one work as well? (Zurich-Dunkirk)

If you buy a separate ticket from Zurich to Mulhouse, you will only need the relevant seat reservation for the Interrail segment

Comment: you woud need a reservation Basel - Paris and Paris - Dunkirk (if taking that route). you do not need a reservation for the Zurich - Basel part, not even on the TGV.